# How to reconfigure the appids of Google Cloud's App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using Google Could’s App Engine for web proxy. I am suspicious that they have been hacked because the key for my google account was changed but I didn't remember changing it. I am encountering increased problems with my web proxy recently. I think sb might have installed sth in my App Engine to spy on my traffic. Since I don't want to give up the free appids, how can I re-install them in order to erase possible malwares?

Comment: Has there been any activity on the activity log for the project in which your App Engine is running? What kind of issues have you been experiencing?